# Confusion about Fragment Communication. Android DatePickerFragment/TimePickerFragment inside of a Fragment,

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am little bit of confused with fragment communication. Android says that Two Fragments should never communicate directly, and I do not know if I violated this rule for my fragment.

Basically, I want to have a Fragment that contains a dropdown spinner, a DatePickerDialog (this will pop up once a user click the edit text), and a TimePickerDialog (This will pop up once a user click the edit text).

Here is what I did so far, right now, when I click on the edit text, the DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog will show up, and everything seems to be working.

But I am kind of worry that I am trying to make two fragments communicate (between my CommonSelectionFragment and DatePickerFragment). Did I violated the rule of Fragment communication? If I did, could you tell me what's a better way to approach this. Thank you very much in advance.

```
    public class CommonSelectionFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnItemSelectedListener {

private Spinner spinner;
private EditText edtTime;
private EditText edtDate;
private static final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_common_selection,
            container, false);

    // populating the spinner with string array of time category
    spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_time_category);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.array.category_array,
            R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    edtTime = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt_time);
    edtTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showTimePickerDialog(v);

        }
    });

    edtDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt_enter_date);
    edtDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDatePickerDialog(v);

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    TextView myText = (TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            "You Selected " + myText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    int year, month, day;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    //  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    }

}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
            "datePicker");
}

public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        //final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
            "timePicker");
}
```

}